# Drag and drop on mobile&tablet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I originally created a drag and drop jquery quiz that works perfectly on desktops, using jquery and jquery ui. Now I would like to have it working on mobile and tablet devices too without changing the existing code. I tried touch punch, but that did not seem to work as expected, even though the code is only using .draggable and .droppable. I have an online version of it at example.themobu.com/Fyq/Template%202/test/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on my end, I'd rather not commit to use YUI3 yet. I'll try this one and report back:

http://popdevelop.com/2010/08/touching-the-web/